# Creating unique ID for tiles in grid from a reference point

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, grid

I need to create an integer (unsigned) ID for tiles in a grid where the following is known:

1. The tiles grow upward and rightward from `(0, 0)`
2. The overall extent is known
3. The first tile is centered on `(0, 0)`

My first idea would be to determine what row, col a tile is in and combine those two numbers; that has been unsuccessful. Following that, I thought I could use the center point of each tile and compute a unique number that represents its distance in the X range and distance in the Y range from `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  So far, you've described a straightforward coordinate system, a lattice of tile units.  I'm unclear on your problem, or what you want from Stack Overflow.  The (x, y) position is a perfectly good identifier for a lattice point; it has been used for centuries with excellent results.

Comment: "that has been unsuccessful": please explain, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know width of the grid - it is `Wdt` tiles wide, then

```
N = Col + Wdt * Row
```

To retrieve tile coordinates from number:

```
Col = N % Wdt      //integer modulo
Row = N // Wdt      //integer division
```